# Fullsize IFrame in firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, iframe

I am having problems with Iframes and Firefox.  Basically, I am embedding an IFrame into a site for it take up the whole body area. It works perfectly with Google chrome as you can see here. The I-frame takes up all the body area, no scrollbars needed to navigate the iframe.

chrome : https://i.stack.imgur.com/muo3U.png

But in firefox it doesn't work correctly. As you can see here, only a part of the iframe is visible and the scrollbars (they are invisible but scrolling works) must be used to navigate the iframe. It is very unappealing for the purpose of my website.

Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vm1O.png

So I'm wondering how I could get this to work?  I have searched and searched and all the solutions I try end up not working.

Here's my code and others I've have tried.

http://pastebin.com/rmdcnLuw

Thanks for any help!

Comment: http://www.pastebin.com/rmdcnLuw , heres the code i've tried, sorry the original post didnt let me post more than two links. Thanks once again for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You need to set your `body` and `html` elements to `height: 100%`**

Try something like this:

```
<html style="height: 100%">
<body style="height: 100%">
    <div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:transparent;">
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com/" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Better yet, add those rules to your CSS file as such:

```
body, html { height: 100%; }
```

---

**You could also try this:**

CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
      <iframe src="http://www.google.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Alternative which moves frameborder and scrolling to the CSS**

`border: none;` removes the border on the iframe, while `overflow: hidden;` disables scrolling and hides any content that's cut off the page (like your original code).

CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; overflow: hidden; }
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
      <iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sadly none of those options worked :/ firefox just doesn't wanna comply with it >.<.

Comment: Weird. It's working for me. The code that you've given on pastebin - is that the entire code?

Comment: Yea thats all the code, what I'm actually doing is embedding the html into a wordpress page, and I just kinda figured whats going on, basically I think firefox might be reading the wordpress Css, before it reads the iframe css, and since it sees that "height = 100%" is already declared for wordpress page, it ignores it in the iframe css, and doesn't apply it, but i figured out if i change the iframe's css to "height = 1000px" , firefox applys it perfectly and so i guess, I'm just gonna figure out how many pixels in height the website im trying to iframe in is, and it should look perfect ^.^

Comment: Ah, I see. That's quite possible.

Comment: yes I did. I had to set the iframe height(inline) manually, since for some reason Chrome does not apply "height = 100%" properly to the iframe.

Comment: Bummer! That's annoying. Just thought I'd ask because I've had a few issues with iframes in Chrome not displaying any scrollbar. A similar solution (setting `height:100%;`) seems to have fixed my problem, though.
Glad you got it working, though! :)

Answer (score 1):

try this in ur css:

```
iframe { display:block; width:100%; border:none;}
```

Comment: `scrolling="no"` is an HTML attribute, not CSS. You may be thinking of `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: @ChrisMorris, thanks for suggetion. I mixed up things. now I have changed it.

Comment: Thanks for the response as well! Sadly applying this css doesnt change anything in firefox :/, it just keeps showing the first quarter top of the site inside the iframe.

Comment: @ChristianAphectsFranco, I don't know much about iframe. But you can use **firebug** in Mozilla , and can try different changes temporarily. So if you succeed, you can commit the changes to your project.

Comment: Thanks for the help tho ^.^, I firgured it out now, not sure if its the right way of doing it but it worked. ^.^

Comment: @ChristianAphectsFranco. Good. you can submit your solution as your own answer in this question you have posted. So you can help others, who are facing the problem like you. :)